# C# - Datastructure with Array of Class/Struct for MemoryMapped file

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

I'm trying to read data via the MemoryMappedViewAccessor and the read data need to be safed into a struct:

```
mmfAccessor.Read(0, out myStruct)
```

The original struct is defined in C++ and it generates fixed sized Arrays of structs into the struct (the structure is fixed and can't be changed):

```
typedef struct
{
int a;
float b;
...
} subStruct

struct MainStruct
{
int a;
float b;
subStruct c[100];
int d[100];
}
```

Now my problem is how to replicate the structure with the Arrays in C#. It's not possible with a struct because there are arrays of other structs and the "unsafe" method in C# is restricted to the basic datatypes (int, float ..).

Do you need additional information?

Comment: It needs [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 100)]

Comment: Okay thanks for that! It definitely solved my initial problem. Now I've ran into the problem that the Read()-method doesn't allow reference types inside the struct.